# Unable to get the response of mongoose query inside Vuejs but works with postman request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

**server side**
first here is how my Api works

```
  searchPosts(params) {
    return Api().get('search', params);
  },
```

```
var postRouter = express.Router();

postRouter.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  var db = req.db;
  Post.find({ capacity: { $lte : req.body.capacity } }, function (error, q) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    res.send({q})
  })
})
```

with this, in my express route im able to do GET request on /search with the body

```
{
    "capacity":60
}
```

for exemple, and have a working-as-intended response

```
{
    "q": [
        {
         "obj":"obj"
        },
     ]
}
```

**Website side**
in my .Vue file i call this function after a clic on a button

```
<v-btn
:disabled="!formIsValid"
flat
color="primary"
type="submit"
@click="searchPost">Search</v-btn>
```

```
  methods: {
    async searchPost() {
      const response = await PostsService.searchPosts({
        capacity: this.form.capacity,
        equipments: this.createObjectFromArray(this.form.equipments),
        date: this.form.date,
        time: this.form.time,
      });
      console.log(response);
      this.availableList = response.q;
    },
```

in postman i'm correctly getting a `q[]` array with all my filtered object inside but on chrome `request` have no `q` inside

for my Api logs, i'm getting no error with Postman but

```
message:
   'Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "capacity" for model "Post"',
  name: 'CastError',
...
```

on the real test on the web

for information, `this.availableList` is defined inside `Data()`

```
 data() {
    const defaultForm = Object.freeze({
      capacity: 0,
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      time: null,
      equipments: [],
    });
    return {
      form: Object.assign({}, defaultForm),
      datePicker: false,
      hourMenu: false,
      availableList: [],
      allList: [],
      defaultForm,
    };
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your capacity field in your Post model includes `type: number`. It probably assumes by default that you're submitting a string value if you do not declare the type as number explicitly in the model.

Also, because you are awaiting the response, you also have to ensure your data assignment waits for the response to return. Try this:

```
methods: {
    async searchPost() {
      const response = await PostsService.searchPosts({
        capacity: this.form.capacity,
        equipments: this.createObjectFromArray(this.form.equipments),
        date: this.form.date,
        time: this.form.time,
      })
      .then( response => {
         console.log(response);
         this.availableList = response.data.q; 
       }
    )}
```

Notice that instead of `response.q` I used `response.data.q`. I can't test this at the moment, so if it doesn't work try switching back to `response.q`.

Answer (score 0):

i've edited my request like so in my vuejs file

```
async searchPost() {
      const response = await PostsService.searchPosts({
        capacity: this.form.capacity,
        equipments: this.createObjectFromArray(this.form.equipments),
        date: this.form.date,
        time: this.form.time,
      });
      this.availableList = response.data;
    },
```

in my Api ive changed it like so

```
  searchPosts(params) {
    return Api().get('search', { params });
  },
```

what a fool was i to try to run a get command by passing parameters inside the body and not the query string

and so, i've updated my get function accordingly

```
postRouter.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  var db = req.db;
  Post.find({ capacity: { $lte : req.query.capacity } }, 'title description capacity equipments resa', function (error, q) {
    if (error) { return res.status(500).send(error); }
    res.send(q);
  })
})
```

to find my find parameter inside req.**query** and no more the body